# Prevent Php/Symfony from type-casting 'true' value

Tags: php, symfony, casting

I have a Symfony (4.3) Form and some validation rules.

In my `App\Entity\Objectif` class :

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="float", options={"default" : 0})
* @Assert\Type("float")
*/
private $budget;
```

In my `App\Form\ObjectifType` class :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder
    ->add('budget')
    ->add('userQuantity')
    /* some other parameters */
;
}
```

In my `App\Controller\ObjectifController` class :

```
public function generateMenu(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ObjectifType::class);
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
    $form->submit($data);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    /* do some stuff with data */
    } else {
      return $this->json('some error message');
    }
}
```

My Symfony application is an API, so I receive data formatted in Json from the frontend.

My goal is to ensure that **value sended by end-user as `$budget` is of float type**.

Problem : the validation process does not work for value 'true'.

If end-user sends a string as `$budget`, the process works and the validation fails as it should.

If end-user sends the value 'true' as `$budget`, that value gets implicitly type-casted as a '1' and so the validation succeed, which souldn't happen.

**How do I force PHP or Symfony to *not* implicitly type-cast 'true' to '1' in that situation ?**

Thank you

---

**TESTS** *(optionnal reading)*

For testing purpose, I put a Callbak validator ([symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html)) in my `App\Entity\Objectif` class, whose only purpose is to output the type of `$budget` property when form is being validated :

```
// App\Entity\Objectif.php

/**
* @Assert\Callback
*/
public function validate(ExecutionContextInterface $context, $payload)
{

dump('Actual value is : ' . $this->budget);

if (!is_float($this->budget)) {
    dump('Value is NOT FLOAT');
    $context->buildViolation('This is not a float type.')
            ->atPath('budget')
            ->addViolation();
    exit;
  } else {
    dump('Value is FLOAT'); 
    exit;
  }
}
```

If I send 'true' as the 'budget' key with my API testing software (Insomnia) :

```
{
    "budget": true
}
```

I always get those outputs :

```
Objectif.php on line 193:
"Actual value is : 1"
Objectif.php on line 202:
"Value is FLOAT"
```

I suspect it is a Symfony problem, because when i use PHP CLI :

```
php > var_dump(is_float(true));
bool(false)
```

I get correct result.

By the way, 'false' value get autocasted to 'null', which doesn't bother regarding my validation purpose, but I don't find if necesary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell you where and why the Form Component changes true to 1 without further investigation but you could use a DataTransferObject and validate against that before submitting the form.

```
class ObjectifDto
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Type("float")
     * @var float
     */
    public $budget;

    public static function fromRequestData($data): self
    {
        $objectifDto= new self();
        $objectifDto->budget = $data['budget'] ?? 0;

        return $objectifDto;
    }
}
```

In the Controller:

```
public function generateMenu(Request $request, ValidatorInterface $validator)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(),true);
    $dto = ObjectifDto::fromRequestData($data);
    $errors = $validator->validate($dto);

    //return errors or go on with the form or persist manually
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I will try what you suggest and give feedback.

Answer (score 1):

So, after some research, I found out that `submit()` method of classes that implements `FormInterface` **do cast every scalar value (i.e. integer, float, string or boolean) to string** (and "false" values to "null") :

```
// Symfony\Component\Form\Form.php
// l. 531 (Symfony 4.3)

if (false === $submittedData) {
          $submittedData = null;
} elseif (is_scalar($submittedData)) {
          $submittedData = (string) $submittedData;
}
```

This has nothing to do with the validation process (which was, in my case, correctly set up).

This explains why I get "true" value casted to "1".

**Someone know why symfony's code is designed that way ? I don't get it.**

I tried to get rid of `submit()` method in my controller by using the more conventionnal `handleRequest()` method. But it does not change anything at all, since `handleRequest` internally calls `submit()` (see `handleRequest()` in HttpFoundationRequestHandler class). So "true" is still casted to "1".

So I ended up using Chris's solution (cf. above). It works perfectly. All credits goes to him :

```
public function generateMenu(
    Request $request,
    ValidatorInterface $validator
)
{
    $data = json_decode(
        strip_tags($request->getContent()),
        true);

    $dto = ObjectifDto::fromRequestData($data);
    $errors = $validator->validate($dto);

    if (count($errors) > 0) {
        $data = [];
        $data['code status'] = 400;
        foreach ($errors as $error) {
            $data['errors'][$error->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
        }
        return $this->json($data, 400);
    } 

    // everything is fine. keep going
}
```

I think it is a good habit to not use Symfony's Form validation process, at least when dealing with API and JSON.

I feel like the 'raw' (so to speak) [Validator](https://symfony.com/doc/4.3/validation.html), combined with DataTransfertObject, gives much more control.
Most importantly, it *does not autocast your values* for whatever reasons (which would totally screw your validation process)...